# SQLAlchemy DataClasses to be separated from normal application specific classes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, architecture

Given SQLAlchemy's ORM wrapper which offers the `MappedAsDataClass` primitive, is it wise (from a code maintenance/readability/design) point of view to abstract away the DB operations into SQLAlchemy Data classes and interface with Python application-specific classes through an independent glue logic; as opposed to merging both of them together?

*Context*: I am building an application which will:

1. Crawl the local outlook ExchangeUser server for employees in the current organization
2. Store the ExchangeUser details (location, business unit, designation etc.) and manager-direct reporting relationships inside a DB

I want to build three tables:

1. **tblUser** (email, name, a unique id to uniquely identify the user) {this information will seldom change - people seldom change their names, organizations rarely change their emails except in M&As or rebrandings)
2. **tblUserDetails**: a little more frequently changing information comprising of location, designation, business unit etc.
3. **tblRelationships**: far more frequently changing information where each employee hash ID is mapped with another employee's hash id reflecting employee, supervisor relationship.

This is the code architecture that I have in mind for this:

[image]

---

A second architecture is to merge the Python application specific classes with DB implementation methods, without the standalone ORM classes.

This is the second architecture that I was originally thinking of
[image]